# asp:GridView doesn't contain control added in OnRowDataBound

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have problem, I can't get control which I added in DataGrid. I am adding it in OnRowDataBound event like:

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit || e.Row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Alternate | DataControlRowState.Edit))
    {
        //int cindex = 0;
        //for (cindex = 0; cindex < e.Row.Controls.Count; cindex++)
        foreach (Control ctl in e.Row.Controls)
        {
            DataControlFieldCell dcctl = (DataControlFieldCell)ctl;
            TableCell tcell = (TableCell)dcctl;

            Label lblComment = new Label();
            TextBox txtComment = new TextBox();

            lblComment.Text = "<br>Comment: ";

            dcctl.Controls.Add(lblComment);
            dcctl.Controls.Add(txtComment);

            //tcell.Controls.Add(lblComment);
            //tcell.Controls.Add(txtComment);

            //e.Row.Cells[cindex].Controls.Add(lblComment);
            //e.Row.Cells[cindex].Controls.Add(txtComment);
```

What is happening here: there is already exist one TextBox in TableCell by default and I want to add another one TextBox and Label. After the bounding I can see 2 textboxes, I can input data into the both, but when I click Update button, then raises `OnRowUpdating` event where I can't get my TextBox!

```
protected void RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        grdView.EditIndex = -1;
        int counter = 0;

        for (counter = 0; counter < grdView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.Count; counter++)
        {
            foreach (Control ctl in grdView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[counter].Controls)
            {
```

And here I will be getting only default one TextBox (with its value). But my TextBox is disappeared! :(

What could you suggest me here to do?

P.S. I can't use predifined columns, like `asp:TemplateField` in aspx file, because my table has different amount of rows every time. It is dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!

Refused of dynamically adding controls in OnRowDataBound, and created dynamical TempalteField columns, which were containing needed to me 2 TextBoxes and Label. (With help of http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/create_template_columns.aspx)

But after my problem returned back.. On OnRowUpdating event still was not having my added TextBoxes. Finally I've found here notice http://forums.asp.net/p/1537632/3738331.aspx, that it is needed to implement TempalteField-s adding on Page_Load, that helped me to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that after you dynamically add a control to a page (or any of the page's child controls such as your datagrid) then you *must* recreate the controls on the server side on postback.  If you don't recreate the controls on the server side, then when the runtime processes the postback it will have no idea where to put the contents of the form post.

So essentially when the page is processing the postback, it sees an HTML field called "gridView1_txtComment" (the actual HTML id is probably something else, I know).  But the server side code model only has an instance of gridView1, there isn't an instance of a TextBox named txtComment *unless* you run the `RowDataBound` method **again** to create that control.

Comment: How should I run RowDataBound again? Could you describe more detailed plz?

Comment: You probably need to restructure the way you're adding those controls.  I can't give you a good (simple) example because the issue is a bit complex.  The main point you have to understand is that: on postback, you are responsible for _recreating_ any dynamically created controls so that the postback handler can fill them with the postback results.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with ViewState.  Make a templated column out of it, then add the second textbox to the template.